# How does kafka streams attempt to get the same partition for each kafka topic?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

If I have multiple application instances, and I am joining two topics, then each instance must get the same partition in order to join on the data. At the same time, it must evenly distribute the partitions among the instances.

If I were to guess, I am thinking that it would randomly request a partition for the first topic, keep that in a context, then request the same partition for all other topics involved in the join?

Can anyone confirm?

Comment: https://www.confluent.io/blog/crossing-streams-joins-apache-kafka/

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to stream joins, it is best to have the underlying topics *co-partitioned*. That way you do not really have to thing about any strange behavior.

That means, as Kafka is by default partitioning the data by key, you would use the key that is used in your join condition as a key of the messages in the kafka topics. That way, together with the *Range* assignment strategy (`partition.assignment.strategy`) on Consumer side you will have an optimal join.

A required condition is to have the same amount of partitions in both topics.

Read more [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#join-co-partitioning-requirements).